# Coded Ui Test - locally passed / remotely not

Tags: coded-ui-tests

My Coded UI Test should Save/Download a File(Pdf, Excel) from IE10 and I am using this code:

```
    var savePopUp = new UITestControl(GetBrowserWindow()) { TechnologyName = "MSAA" };
    savePopUp.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.ControlType, "ToolBar");
    savePopUp.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name, "Benachrichtigung");

    var saveButton = new UITestControl(savePopUp) { TechnologyName = "MSAA" };
    saveButton.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.ControlType, "SplitButton");
    saveButton.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name, "Speichern unter");
    Mouse.Click(saveButton);
```

If I run this locally for testing my code works fine but remotely the controls will not be found.

How do I make the test work remotely?

Comment: Is your browser the same on the remote computer?  I would try manually going through your steps to get to the control in question and then look at the source to make sure that your definition of that element on that browser is the same as your code.

Comment: 1. The Browser Versions are exactly the same (IE 10). 2. I have to interact with WinControls so maybe the language is different -> I will check it. Thx